# Controller cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 site. I have an ArtistController within the Controllers folder.

The ArtistController has a Get method:

```
public ActionResult Get(string paramOne, string paramTwo)
```

In RouteConfig.cs I have this route, before Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "artistApi",
            url: "api/artist/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Artist", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I try to test this call, I get:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI. No type was found that matches the controller named 'Artist'.

It works if I remove the api part from the route:

```
url: "artist/{action}/{id}"
```

I am not using WebApi, just a normal Controller.

Any idea on why this route doesn't find the controller?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the test URL look like?

Comment: The URL looks like this: api/Artist/Albums?paramOne=ArtistName&paramTwo=otherValue

Comment: I have changed the url value to "test/artist/{action}" and now it is working. It seems to me that you can only use "api/controller" using web API. any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a WebApiConfig.cs file in your App_Start folder.  This may be overriding your route definition.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I uninstalled web API and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your routes are not ordered properly - if `api/` is before your more specific route it will match first and never reach your new route.

```
// More specific routes should go before generic ones:
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "artistApi",
        url: "api/artist/{action}/{id}",...);
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: No, the routes are ordered properly. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understands correctly,

url: "api/artist/{action}/{id}" line takes id as your querystring

ex www.yourwebsite/youractioncontroller/1

your actionResult takes two querystring which MVC does not understand what to do

one morething is "artist" need to be your controller which normally
{controller}

or your  artist controller should be artistContoller

Comment: It sounds reasonable... but I have this url: api/Artist/Albums?paramOne=ArtistName&paramTwo=otherValue, how can I create the route to accept this?

Comment: might be like {controller}/{action}/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}/